# How to hide an item in the extended menu?

Tags: windows-10, windows-registry, context-menu

when I add an item in the context menu it is also added in the extended menu, is there any way to avoid that? (I just want to display it in the normal context menu, and hide it in the extended menu that is enabled by pressing SHIFT+CLICK)

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\Name]
"MUIVerb"="Name"
"Icon"="\"xyz.ico\""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\Name\command]
@=...
```

Comment: Windows 10?????

Comment: Yes, Windows 10